# Java Generics of the form <T extends A<T>> and Eclipse Compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, generics, compiler-errors

I have another interesting problem with Java Generics. I'm sure, some of you might have the right answer to it.

*Context.*
First, to understand the context, let's look at the definition of the objects Animal, Mammal, and Cat, which are defined in terms of each other:

```
public abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    private final int age;

    public Animal(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public abstract T setAge(int age);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Mammal<?>> mammals = new ArrayList<Mammal<?>>();
        mammals = Animal.increaseAge(mammals, 1);
        Map<Integer, List<Mammal<?>>> mammalsByAge = Animal.groupByAge(mammals);
    }

    public static <T extends Animal<T>> List<T> increaseAge(List<T> animals, int augment) {
        List<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
        for (T animal : animals) {
            list.add(animal.setAge(animal.getAge() + augment));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static <T extends Animal<T>> Map<Integer, List<T>> groupByAge(List<T> animals) {
        Map<Integer, List<T>> animalsPerAge = new TreeMap<Integer, List<T>>();
        animals.forEach((animal) -> {
            int age = animal.getAge();
            animalsPerAge.putIfAbsent(age, new LinkedList<T>());
            animalsPerAge.get(age).add(animal);
        });
        return animalsPerAge;
    }

};

abstract class Mammal<T extends Mammal<T>> extends Animal<Mammal<T>> {
    public Mammal(int age) {
        super(age);
    }
};

class Cat extends Mammal<Cat> {
    public Cat(int age) {
        super(age);
    }

    @Override
    public Cat setAge(int age) {
        return new Cat(age);
    }
}
```

Later, I will have different animals and mammals, obviously. Imported also, all elements must implement a 'copy-on-write' policy, i.e., changing a property of an animal creates a new animal of the same type with the new property in place.

Finally, I need to implement two helper functions, `groupByAge`, and `increaseAge`.

*Problem.*
In the beginning, I realized that the Eclipse IDE can compile and execute the program, whereas the Maven compiler failed with a compiler error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
(default-compile) on project BCBS248Calculator: Compilation failure:
Compilation failure:

[ERROR] Animal.java:[25,33] method increaseAge in class
com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Animal<Tcannot be applied to given types;

[ERROR] required: java.util.List<T>,int

[ERROR] found: java.util.List<com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Mammal<?>>,int

[ERROR] reason: inferred type does not conform to equality
constraint(s)

[ERROR] inferred: com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Mammal<capture#1 of ?>

[ERROR] equality constraints(s): com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Mammal<capture#1
of ?>,com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Mammal<?>

[ERROR] Animal.java:[27,68] method groupByAge in class
com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Animal<Tcannot be applied to given types;

[ERROR] required: java.util.List<T>

[ERROR] found: java.util.List<com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Mammal<?>>

[ERROR] reason: inferred type does not conform to equality
constraint(s)

[ERROR] inferred: com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Mammal<capture#2 of ?>

[ERROR] equality constraints(s): com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Mammal<capture#2
of ?>,com.ibm.ilm.bcbs248.Mammal<?>
```

At first glance, I thought this is a Maven-Problem (because Eclipse can compile and execute the code), but in reality, it seems to be a bug *(?)* in the Eclipse compiler. Even the normal Java compiler is not able to compile the program, it terminates with a type error as the program cannot be verified. This a well-known problem with Java generics, i.e., the Java type checker cannot verify the program at this point. This is simply due to the approximation of the static type checker.

As far as I know, Eclipse uses an own Java compiler, i.e., a wrapper around the original Java compiler that allowed to compile malicious programs? However, in this situation, it does not show any error message? Can anybody verify that is this a problem with the  Eclipse compiler?

Moreover, does anybody have another elegant idea on how to solve the coding problem? As a simple word-around, I can change the type signature of both helper function as follows:

```
public static <T extends Animal<?>> List<T> increaseAge(List<T> animals, int augment) {
    List<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
    for (T animal : animals) {
        list.add((T) animal.setAge(animal.getAge() + augment));
    }
    return list;
}

public static <T extends Animal<?>> Map<Integer, List<T>> groupByAge(List<T> animals) {
    Map<Integer, List<T>> animalsPerAge = new TreeMap<Integer, List<T>>();
    animals.forEach((animal) -> {
        int age = animal.getAge();
        animalsPerAge.putIfAbsent(age, new LinkedList<T>());
        animalsPerAge.get(age).add(animal);
    });
    return animalsPerAge;
}
```

Unfortunately, I also need to add a type cast in line `list.add((T) animal.setAge(animal.getAge() + augment));`. I can live with the changed type signature, but I will get rid of the typecast as it ends in uncertainties.

Re-adding an element of the same type seems not to be a problem with the changes type-signature. However, after calling `setAge` some type of information seems to be lost. Maybe I can change the type of the function or object in a way that this works?

--

Maven version 3.1

Java version 1.8.0_201
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

Comment: Really using Maven 3.1. ? I recommend to upgrade your Maven version (Maven 3.6.1) and probably other tools as well..like Eclipse to most recent 2019-03 ...which will not fix the issue cause it's related to other things as shown in the Answer.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the historic versions are given (defined) by the project. But newer versions did not solve the problem.

Comment: What's the class diagram of your classes? Would be great if you can add it.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought this is a Maven-Problem

Maven is just a build tool. If you're getting a compiler error, it's nothing to do with Maven.

> Eclipse uses an own Java compiler, i.e., a wrapper around the original
>   Java compiler that allowed to compile malicious programs

Eclipse has a different compiler, yes. 'Malicious' is not correct. It supports incremental compilation (only re-compile code when it has changed). It can compile and run code with compile-time errors, deferring them to a runtime exception instead.

> Can anybody verify that is this a problem with the Eclipse compiler?

As you said yourself: "Even the normal Java compiler is not able to compile the program". So the answer is no. Your program is just incorrect.

---

Your problem basically stems from the fact that I don't think these are meaningful generic type parameters

```
Animal<T extends Animal<T>>
Mammal<T extends Mammal<T>>
```

When I see a generic type parameter, I try to insert the words 'to' or 'of' and see if it makes sense.

`List<String>` is a list **of** strings. `Comparable<String>` is something that can be compared **to** strings. A `Listener<Message>` listens **to** messages.

So then what is `Mammal<Cat>`? A mammal **of** cats? A mammal **to** cats? Do you see how it doesn't make sense in the same way?

You're trying to use generics to propagate up knowledge of the child class to the parent class. That is not what they're for.

---

Here is how your code looks when you remove the generic type parameters. There is one unchecked cast, but we know that any setter is guaranteed to return an object of the same type, so its safe to ignore it.

```
abstract class Animal {
    private final int age;

    public Animal(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public abstract Animal setAge(int age);

    public static <T extends Animal> List<T> increaseAge(List<T> animals, int augment) {
        List<T> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (T animal : animals) {
            list.add((T) animal.setAge(animal.getAge() + augment));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static <T extends Animal> Map<Integer, List<T>> groupByAge(List<T> animals) {
        Map<Integer, List<T>> animalsPerAge = new TreeMap<>();
        animals.forEach((animal) -> {
            int age = animal.getAge();
            animalsPerAge.putIfAbsent(age, new LinkedList<>());
            animalsPerAge.get(age).add(animal);
        });
        return animalsPerAge;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Mammal> mammals = new ArrayList<>();
        mammals = Animal.increaseAge(mammals, 1);
        Map<Integer, List<Mammal>> mammalsByAge = Animal.groupByAge(mammals);
    }
};

abstract class Mammal extends Animal {
    public Mammal(int age) {
        super(age);
    }
}

class Cat extends Mammal {
    public Cat(int age) {
        super(age);
    }

    @Override
    public Cat setAge(int age) {
        return new Cat(age);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I disagree. The program is syntactically and semantically correct: There is no syntax error and no a runtime error. But the Java type checker cannot type-check the program. This is due to the approximation of static type-checkers. So the program is not type-correct i.r.t. the Java type-checker.

Comment: Regarding the definition of generics: Java Generics is a kind of type polymorphism, enabling programs to operate on various types while still providing type-safety. So, why should the class definition be inappropriate?    The intention of the given type-definition is to specify abstract methods in terms of concrete (child) types, e.g., method setAge which is defined in Animal and when calling the method on a Cat it returns a Cat. This is a well-known use case for type polymorphism. But I'm open to improvements to the class definition!

Comment: 'Syntactically incorrect' was perhaps a poor choice of words. Your program is not valid Java - and the type system is part of that. There is no compiler issue. Semantically correct? Sorry but no.

Comment: Sorry but this is not correct. There is a clear definition of syntax and semantics. My program is semantically correct. You can execute it without errors! Moreover, most type-information gets removed after compiling the source code, so it is not necessary for execution. And there is no syntax error, as the code confirms to the syntax definition of Java.

Comment: You are right, the program is not valid Java due to the type-checker, which is part of Java. So it is not type-correct! However, Java knows that its type-checker fails at some point and rejects 'correct' programs. Therefore they introduced some language constructs to make the type-checker happy. One of those is the cast-operation .. and with a type-cast, you can make my example "type"-valid.

Comment: "My program is semantically correct. You can execute it without errors!" This is not a logical conclusion. The following code executes without errors, but is not semantically correct `public static int add(int a, int b) { return a - b; }`

Comment: "There is a clear definition of syntax and semantics" never said there wasn't. "And there is no syntax error" never said there was. You are arguing with things I never said. I already said that mentioning syntax was a mistake and I've edited it out of my answer...

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, the problem is not the method body. The type error says that the list given as argument does not fit the type signature of the method(s). In the end, it boils down to the standard covariance and contravariance problem of lists with generics. Somehow I thought that I could be clever and bypass the uncertainties by using nested generics like `Animal<Mammal<T>>` and concrete method signatures, but it seems that it only grafted the problem to another place.

*To sum up possible solutions:*

The second method call (`groupByAge`) can be fixed by using the wildcard `?`, like `<T extends Animal<?>>`. This works as we only move an element of type `T` to another list of type `T`.

The first method call (`increaseByAge`) is trickier. We can also add the wildcard `?` to the type signature of the method, however, then we lose the information that we have an element of type `T` after calling `setAge` (`setAge` returns then an element of type `Animal<?>`).

*Someone another idea how to address this, maybe by using another type signature for Animal?*

Obviously, a typecast would solve this problem, but type casts are not acceptable (even if their only purpose is to make the type checker happy).

Another possible solution would be to completely remove the generic types from `Mammal` at the list definition, like `List<Mammal> mammals = new ArrayList<Mammal>();`. However, this also leads to unchecked operations and is therefore out.

Obviously, the code also types-checks if we use concrete lists, like a list of `Cat`'s or a list of `Dog`'s, like `List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();`. However, the situation requires to have a common list for cats and dogs in this situation.

Finally, it remains to have type-specific `increaseByAge`-methods, for example, an `increaseByAge` methods for lists of mammals, maybe also implement in the `Mammal` class.

```
public static  List<Mammal<?>> increaseByAge(List<Mammal<?>> mammals, int augment) {
     List<Mammal<?>> list = new LinkedList<Mammal<?>>();
     for (Mammal<?> mammal : mammals) {
         mammal = mammal.setAge(mammal.getAge() + augment);
         list.add(mammal);
     }
     return list;
 }
```

One can remove the generic type from the method and focus directly on lists of mammals. Unfortuantly, this requires to have multiple `increaseByAge` methods, one for each group of animals.

I'm still open to other solutions. Maybe somebody also sees another idea of how to write the generic types of the objects to make this easier.

*Despite all the discussion on the generic types, it remains to mention that this seems to be a bug in the Eclipse type checker.  Whereas the standard Java compiler cannot compile this code, the Eclipse IDE compiled the code nor does it show any type error.*